# Regex extract data before certain text

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have large text documents that has some data I want to be extracted.

As you can see in a screenshot [image], I want to extract **A040** to excel column next to the filename.

Before the **A040** there is always three empty spaces and than text **Sheet** (also in screenshot)

Every file has different number and there is always letter A with three digits and text Sheet. --> example file uploaded: [image]

I has something already in VB with Excel but it is not working.

```
Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim output As String

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)

    For Each cell In rng

        On Error Resume Next
        output = ExtA(cell.Value)

        If Len(output) > 0 Then
            Range("B" & j) = output
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    j = j + 1
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    'Call DelConns

    strFileName = Dir 'next file

Loop
End Sub

Function ExtA(ByVal text As String) As String
'REGEX Match VBA in excel

Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = "(?<=Sheet)[^Sheet]*\ Sheet"
RE.Global = True
RE.IgnoreCase = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

If allMatches.Count <> 0 Then
    result = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
End If

ExtA = result

End Function
```

Comment: This looks like VBA and not VB.NET. In VBA, regex does not support lookbehinds. You need to replace `"(?<=Sheet)[^Sheet]*\ Sheet"` with something like `"\b[A-Z0-9]+(?=\s+Sheets+\d+/\d+)"`

Comment: Yea, soory, I've changed it correctly, but this is not working, I've tried it now

Comment: You mean AFTER the A040 there is always three empty spaces and than text Sheet (not before)? How does all that look in an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: You could use a pattern like this and use submatches to extract the bracketed section `(A[0-9]{3})\s{3}Sheet`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work on your sample.

```
Option Explicit

Function AthreeDigits(str As String)
    Dim n As Long, nums() As Variant
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Else
        Set cmat = Nothing
    End If
    AthreeDigits = vbNullString

    With rgx
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\A[0-9]{3}[\s]{3}Sheet"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            AthreeDigits = Left(cmat.Item(0), 4)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: You could eliminate the `Left` by using something like: `.Pattern = "A\d{3}(?=\s+Sheet)"`

Comment: Good point. I'm afraid my regex patterns are very verbose and non-eloquent but hopefully I got the boilerplate functionality close to something the OP can use.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to say that there are 4 spaces *after* the A040 and before the "Sheet"? If so, try this pattern:

```
.pattern = "(A\d\d\d)\s{3}Sheet"
```

EDIT: I thought you said 4 spaces, but you said 3. My pattern now reflects that.
EDIT 2: (I need more coffee!) Change the \b to \s.

Answer (score 0):

*See Example here*

***`"\s+[Aa]\d*\s+Sheet"`*** 
*Or* 

***`\s+[Aa]\d*\s+(Sheet)`***
*Or* 

***`[Aa]\d*\s+(Sheet)`***

*Demo*
***https://regex101.com/r/Qo8iUf/3***

> [image]

***`\s+`*** Matches any whitespace character (equal to **`[\r\n\t\f\v ]`**)
**`+`** Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
**`Aa`** Matches a single character in the list **`Aa`** (case sensitive)
**`\d*`** Matches a digit (equal to **`[0-9]`**)
**`*`** Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible

> [image]